# What is the use of firebug's "Open With Editor" function?

Tags: css, xhtml, firebug, firefox-addon

What is the use of firebug's "Open With Editor" function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say it'll allow you to visualize a file / feed with an editor -- which means better searching features, syntax-highlighting, better-ability to copy code...

But it means you have to configure the editors, so firebug knows how to call one -- especially, so it knows how to pass it the data.

**Edit after the comment :** no, I don't see it allows you to see your modifications into the website -- but it's, I think, easier to go through the HTML code this way, with the editor you're using in your every-day life as a developer.

For example, you can check what's said in this article : [Check Edit HTML Code with Firebug](http://supermunk.wordpress.com/2009/07/22/check-edit-html-code-with-firebug/) -- check the *Editing With Firebug* section.

And to use it, you have to :

- select something like "`Open with editor > Configure editors`", and, in the dialog box, set the path to your editor
- and, then, to edit some HTML page, select "`Open with editor > name of your editor`"

*(The labels may not be exactly those : I'm using the french version...)*

Comment: no, you can't save it back to the page you got it from, but you can view and analyze it easily

Answer (score 0):

You can use cssUpdater to save your modified css directly after you have changed the property in FireBug -> http://www.cssUpdater.com